# Flutter: Local Notifications Plugin showing notification twice

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, flutter-local-notification

I am receiving notification from my server at a specific time to show users a notification. However, whenever my device receives a message from Firebase Cloud Messaging `FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin` ends up showing two notifications as seen below.

[image]

I already confirmed that I am receiving one notification from my server, its just that somewhere in the front end its being handled incorrectly I think.

Here is my code where I am calling this in the background

`main`

```dart
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
  if (message.notification != null) {
    print(message.notification.title);
    print(message.notification.body);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        message.notification.hashCode,
        message.notification.title,
        message.notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channel.description,
            icon: 'launch_background',
          ),
          iOS: IOSNotificationDetails()
        ));
  }

  // Create a notification for this
}


const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
  importance: Importance.high,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

// Starting FlutterFire through the suggestion found here
// https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
  /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
  /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
  /// heads up notifications.
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  User _user;
  FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  bool _error = false;

  void _handleLogin(User user) {
    // print("Handle Login");
    setState(() {
      _user = user;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // if we opened the app through a notification, it will send us via this
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('On Message Opened!');
      print(message);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles across this same issue. I re-read the documentation on [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/) where it mentions if you have the current up-to-date Flutter SDK and Firebase, then it will try to display it automatically. My mistake was that I implemented `FlutterLocalNotifications` in addition to this and I was receiving two notifications where one was manual and the other automatic.

When sending a message to your device, make sure it is a `notification` rather than `data`. The documentation mentions that if you send `data` it will likely be ignored as a push notification. Only use it to send packets of data to the app instead.

Comment: Any way to handle the `notification` type manually for IOS? so it is not showing automatically?

Comment: In that case, you would want to send your notification as a `data` type rather than `notification`. You can choose to manually show it via `FlutterLocalNotifications`

Comment: yes, I know the data is not triggered automatically. but unfortunately, I can not change that from the server-side and want to handle it from the Flutter side.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this issue, as i want to play a custom notification sound only when app is in background or terminated state and if i implement onBackgroundMessage i am getting two notifications one automatic and another manual

Comment: @Himankshah have you found any solution for custom notifications when app is terminated?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the notification object from the payload it will hide and avoid 2 notification problems but it will not consider in the firebase messaging reports section.

Here is a Screenshot of the report with notification it shows but without notification, it doesn't

[cloud message report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp1oG.png)

Answer (score -2):

Commenting this part of the code solves the issue.

/// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
/// heads up notifications.
await

> FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
> alert: true,
> badge: true,
> sound: true,   );

Comment: Not working in my case